# Readiness probe gives out of service error

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kubernetes, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I have updated spring boot to `2.5.2` from `2.1.8.RELEASE`. Before that liveness and readiness probe was fine. Now after updating the spring boot I have updated my application properties file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=health,info
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.enable.*=true
management.metrics.enable.all=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.use-global-registry=true




management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessstate.enabled=true
management.health.readinessstate.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

I have added last 4 lines respective to some documents.

After starting the project locally and checking from browser:

`http://localhost:8090/actuator/health/liveness` gives `{"status":"UP"}`

But
`http://localhost:8090/actuator/health/readiness` gives `{"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE"}` which is 503 status.

```
{
    "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",
    "components": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 499963174912,
                "free": 326313852928,
                "threshold": 10485760,
                "exists": true
            }
        },
        "livenessState": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "ping": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "readinessState": {
            "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
        }
    },
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ]

}
```

In my pom file under dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: There have been changes in the actuator/probes in Spring Boot 2.3. Do you do something in your code working on the states?

Comment: No I didn't change anything in the code base, like I mentioned only updated the application property. Is there any requirements in the code base?

Comment: No but it might be something existing in the codebase that acts different now than what it was earlier because of the changes in ReadinessState

Comment: Anything particular you are suggesting?

Comment: Why is the starter-web on runtime scope? And furthermore why is starter-acutator on scope runtime?

Comment: Throws Dependency problems found without putting them as scope runtime and also throws warning unused.

Comment: Because of the enforcer

Comment: Can you provide a sample reproducing the error?

Comment: what kind of sample do you require? It is a full fledged project @Shawrup

Comment: I tried with your code but I could not reproduce the issue. readiness works perfectly in my sample app. So I could not figure out the issue. A sample project reproducing the issue might be helpful.

Comment: Can you check if you get more output if you set: `endpoints.health.sensitive : false`?

Comment: I don't know how can I provide you a sample application, it's a full fledge project @Shawrup

Comment: Adding management.endpoints.health.sensitive=false doesn't show anything extra @LukasEichler

Comment: I am facing the same issue after updating 2.4.5 to 2.5.4.

Comment: So readinnes probe is showing UP after this method is called `EventPublishingRunListener.running(..)`. Doc says: `Called immediately before the run method finishes, when the application context has been refreshed and all CommandLineRunners and ApplicationRunners have been called.` So i added breakpoint to all my run methods of ApplicationRunner, CommandLineRunner implementations and find out that one of those realy gets stucked. In my case it has something to do with azure blob storage library.